# How can I moved a .js file in my react-native project to a different directory

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to rearrange my files and folders in an inherited project but to project fails to build when I move any of the files to another location.

The error I get is:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/screens/images'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:887:3)
    at Object.getDirFiles (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:103:34)
    at Map._factory (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/AssetResolutionCache.js:41:36)
    at Map.get (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/lib/MapWithDefaults.js:23:24)
    at AssetResolutionCache.resolve (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/AssetResolutionCache.js:91:43)
    at resolveAsset (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:229:36)
    at resolveAssetFiles (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:463:22)
    at resolveFile (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:349:20)
    at resolveFileOrDir (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:262:22)
    at resolveModulePath (/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:184:18)
```

I have checked the file paths being referenced in other files and cant find a problem.

Also the file in the error message doesn't actually exist '/screens/images/' so don't know where that came from/

Any troubleshooting steps you can think of?

I have restarted VS code, the metro bundler, reset cache etc etc.

Comment: can you post the code snippet where you try to load the file?

Comment: @messerbill, Sorry but what do you mean? THe code for the file I am trying to move?

Comment: no i am talking about the code line where you try to import that file

Comment: // WorkoutOverview.js
import WorkoutInProgress from './WorkoutInProgress/WorkoutInProgress';

Comment: i am talking about that part where your app wants to import / load that one: `'/Users/serdar/Work/tone-and-sculpt-front-end/screens/images'`

Comment: I don't, it doesn't exist so I have no idea how it is in the error message.